# Grab a script and reload it ? jQuery

Tags: jquery, ajax, reload

I have the following:

```
<div id="some-id"></div><script src="/script.js" type="text/javascript">
```

I'm trying to basically use the `some-id` to grab the script and reload it ? How would I do this via ajax ?

i.e. like

`var scriptLoad = jQuery('#some-id').next().attr('src');`

Then reload the `src`

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish with a reload of the script?  Is there not just some function in the script that you can just call again?

Comment: @jfriend00 - the script is loaded and assigned dynamically attributed key value from the server each time. It's easier to do it this way

Comment: The more conventional way of doing this would be to make an ajax call to the server to retrieve the desired JSON data.  It would be easier to track completion and errors with ajax too and various libraries like jQuery have very simple support for ajax calls.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get the next sibling, load the source path, append a querystring to clear any cache. (changing the src causes the script to reload)

```
var sc = $("#some-id").next();
var src = sc.attr("src");
sc.attr("src", (sc.indexOf("?") == -1 ? "?" : "&") + "c=" + Math.random());
```

Comment: @BrunoLM - thanks for the response :) can't seem to get the script to reload via ajax ? Instead, should I just use `$.ajax({url: src, dataType: "script", success: success});`

Answer (score 0):

Try this, it will reload the script tag in the head tag of the page.

```
$("head").append($("#some-id").find("script:first"));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<div id="some-id"></div>
<script id="my-script" src="/script.js" type="text/javascript">


$('#my-script').setAttribute("src", "/script.js");
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
jQuery('#some-id').next().clone().appendTo(document.body);
```